# How to get over "device or resource busy"?

Tags: files, lock

I tried to `rm -rf` a folder, and got "device or resource busy".

In Windows, I would have used LockHunter to resolve this. What's the linux equivalent? (Please give as answer a simple "unlock this" method, and not complete articles like [this one](http://www.innovationsts.com/blog/?p=658). Although they're useful, I'm currently interested in just ASimpleMethodThatWorks™)

Comment: Thanks this was handy - I was coming from Linux to Windows, was looking for the equivalent of lsof - LockHunter.

Comment: What the hell?  Unix does *not* prevent you from deleting open files like Windows does.  This is why you can delete your whole system by running `rm -rf /`... it will happily delete every single file, including /bin/rm.

Comment: @psusi, that is incorrect. You either have a bad source of information or are just making stuff up. Linux, like Windows, has file and device locking. It's kind of broken, though. http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/locking.html

Comment: @foobarbecue, normally those are only advisory locks and the man page at least seems to indicate they are only for read/write, not unlink.

Comment: Solutions on this page don't work for me, still not be able to delete the file, but in my case i'm bothered by the size the file, so i do this little trick: `vim unwanted_file`, then simply **delete the content inside the file** in edit mode, this way i release the disk, but the file is still there.

Comment: why nobody is telling to delete the folder in host machine? I was getting this error in docker container, and it was the fastest way to delete with sudo from host machine but no google first results where telling that, no answer like this here. I would post an answer but I cannot because I need more reputation. And this is ASimpleMethodThatWorks at least in case like my. No need to install things like lsof, tried that - it even gave me erorr that it failed to download or smth.

Answer (score 402, accepted):

The tool you want is `lsof`, which stands for *list open files*.

It has a lot of options, so check the man page, but if you want to see all open files under a directory:

```
lsof +D /path
```

That will recurse through the filesystem under `/path`, so beware doing it on large directory trees.

Once you know which processes have files open, you can exit those apps, or kill them with the `kill(1)` command.

Comment: What if there were no results?

Comment: @marines: Check if another filesystem is mounted beneath `/path`. That is one cause of hidden "open files".

Comment: lsof command directly to the path does not work. So basically need to go in the path location and then run lsof busy_file then kill all the process

Comment: `lsof` seems to do nothing for me: `lsof storage/logs/laravel.log` returned nothing, and so did `lsof +D storage/logs/`. `umount` responded with `not mounted`.

Comment: Just to elaborate on @camh answer: Use `mount | grep <path>`. That shows any `/dev/<abc>` might be mounted on the the `<path>`. Use `sudo umount -lf /dev/<abc>` and then try to remove `<path>`. Works for me. Thanks @camh

Comment: @marines use sudo?

Comment: umount worked for me

Comment: What worked for me on our remote university server was `lsof +D /FULL/PATH` followed by `kill -9 PID`. You can then check by simply rerunning the first command (`lsof +D /FULL/PATH`) and you should see `[1]+ Killed`

Comment: Just encountered another case: loop device even not mounted. Seen in GUI of Gnome disk utility and via `losetup`. Detaching device solved the issue. (BTW iso file on which loop was "based" was not found by `lsof +D /folder_where_iso_was`).

Comment: @camh this solved my issue, I was running inside docker and the host mounted the same directory.

Comment: This answer would be **much improved** if the author explained it. For example, say I get a *"device or resource busy"* message for `/mnt/something`... what is it that goes in the "path" of`lsof +D /path` ??

Answer (score 208):

sometimes it's the result of mounting issues, so I'd unmount the filesystem or directory you're trying to remove:

> umount /path

Comment: in my case, Jenkins didn't unmount chroot dir after task abort

Comment: In my case I cannot unmount _because_ the device is busy.

Comment: You would think the mount command would first do a umount to ensure the path was clear...

Comment: Late to the party but maybe useful for feature checks, mount the dir rather than mounting the file, because that was causing me the issue.

Answer (score 32):

I had this same issue, built a one-liner starting with @camh recommendation:

```
lsof +D ./ | awk '{print $2}' | tail -n +2 | xargs -r kill -9
```

- `awk` grabs the PIDs.
- `tail` gets rid of
  the pesky first entry: "PID".
- `xargs` executes `kill -9` on the PIDs. The `-r` / `--no-run-if-empty`, prevents `kill` command failure, in case `lsof` did not return any PID.

Comment: @ChoyltonB.Higginbottom as you asked for a safer way to prevent `kill <no PID>` failure (if lsof returns nothing) - Use xargs with `-r / --no-run-if-empty`. For non-GNU xargs, see this alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19038748

Comment: You can pipe `tail -n +2` output through `sort -u` before killing the jobs IDs

Comment: `kill -9` is a favorite for use but does have serious implications. This signal is "non-catchagable, non-ignorable" to the process. Thus, the process may terminate without saving critical state data. Perhaps a simple `kill` first, and if that doesn't work, then the `-9`? Finally, bear in mind that if the process is blocked on I/O, `kill -9` isn't going to work. That's not an oversight in this suggestion, just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 20):

I experience this frequently on servers that have NFS network file systems. I am assuming it has something to do with the filesystem, since the files are typically named like `.nfs000000123089abcxyz`.

My typical solution is to rename or move the parent directory of the file, then come back later in a day or two and the file will have been removed automatically, at which point I am free to delete the directory.

This typically happens in directories where I am installing or compiling software libraries.

Comment: I also have the same problem with `.nfsxxx` files dropped seemingly in random places. However, I am not sure how this suggestion can make sense - obviously renaming the parent directory does not work because its contents are locked. Wouldn't get the error in the first instance otherwise. I tried it and simply nothing happens, the renaming refuses to happen. Do you want to elaborate/have any other suggestion?

Comment: renaming the parent directory always worked for me. No clue why. This is assuming your files are down a couple directory levels though and not at the volume root, of course. Sorry I dont have a better answer than "it just works for me".

Answer (score 19):

Here is the solution:

1. Go into the directory and type `ls -a`
2. You will find a `.xyz` file
3. `vi .xyz` and look into what is the content of the file
4. `ps -ef | grep username`
5. You will see the .xyz content in the 8th column (last row)
6. `kill -9 job_ids` - where job_ids is the value of the 2nd column of corresponding error caused content in the 8th column
7. Now try to delete the folder or file.

Comment: It would be interesting to know where those mysterious files are coming from.

Comment: This doesn't work in my situation, there simply is no .xyz file.

Comment: For me lsof does not work but I am able to use this

Answer (score 18):

I use `fuser` for this kind of thing.  It will list which process is using a file or files within a mount.

Comment: `fuser` helps only in the specific case when you want to unmount a filesystem. Here the problem is to find what's using a specific file.

Comment: @Gilles: Also works for files.

Comment: Sorry, wrong objection: `fuser` doesn't help here because the problem is to find all the open files in a directory tree. You can tell `lsof` to show all files and filter, or make it recurse; `fuser` has no such mode and needs to be invoked on every file.

Comment: @Giles: `fuser` works will lists. Try `fuser /var/log/*`,  if any logs are open it will tell which ones and who has it open.  If a simple wildcard, won't work, `find` with or without `xargs` will do the job.

Comment: `lsof` was not in my path while `fuser` was, allowing me to find the offending process ID to kill, so +1+thanks.

Comment: `fuser -v` also shows kernel mounts (vfs).

Answer (score 13):

Riffing off of Prabhat's question above, I had this issue in macos high sierra when I stranded an encfs process, rebooting solved it, but this

```
ps -ef | grep name-of-busy-dir
```

Showed me the process and the PID (column two).

```
sudo kill -15 pid-here
```

fixed it.

Comment: This worked for me too. Whats the `-15`?

Comment: @O.rka 15 is the id of the SIGTERM signal, see here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317492/list-of-kill-signals

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem when an automated test created a ramdisk. The commands suggested in the other answers, `lsof` and `fuser`, were of no help. After the tests I tried to unmount it and then delete the folder. I was really confused for ages because I couldn't get rid of it -- I kept getting *"Device or resource busy"*!

By accident I found out how to get rid of a ramdisk. I had to unmount it the same number of times that I had run the `mount` command, i.e.
`sudo umount path`

Due to the fact that it was created using automated testing, it got mounted many times, hence why I couldn't get rid of it by simply unmounting it once after the tests. So, after I manually unmounted it lots of times it finally became a regular folder again and I could delete it.

Answer (score 8):

If you have the server accessible, Try

> Deleting that dir from the server

Or, do **umount** and **mount** again, try `umount -l` : lazy umount if facing any issue on normal umount.

I too had this problem where

`lsof +D path` : gives no output

`ps -ef` : gives no relevant information