# Unable to re-create /tmp directory

Tags: debian, systemd, tmp

Recently, I have found that my debian 8.2 (jessie) installation is taking forever to boot because systemd will hang for several minutes on `a start job is running for create volatile files and directories`. I have consulted various debian forums that have provided the solution of deleting the /tmp directory and re-creating it.

http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=118008

However, when I tried to do this, I got the error: `cannot remove /tmp device or resource busy`. I have already come across another forum where this is discussed, but none of their solutions are working for me (lsof and umount).

[How to get over "device or resource busy"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11238/how-to-get-over-device-or-resource-busy)

These are (currently) the contents of my /tmp directory:

```
chris@debian:/tmp$ ls -a
.                 lu7rao5i.tmp
..                orbit-chris
gnucash.trace     OSL_PIPE_1000_SingleOfficeIPC_d3a739592b2fd367937df734e849bd3
hsperfdata_chris  systemd-private-72f0212651f2433dbce43b96e2dea612-cups.service-9OArRS
kde-chris
```

I will provide output to any requested bash commands.

EDIT 1:

```
chris@debian:~$ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=1017089,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1630924k,mode=755)
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=22,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
rpc_pipefs on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=815464k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
chris@debian:~$ getenforce
bash: getenforce: command not found
chris@debian:~$ sudo getenforce
[sudo] password for chris: 
sudo: getenforce: command not found
chris@debian:~$ ls -ld /tmp/
drwxrwxrwt 8 root root 247619584 Jan  9 18:35 /tmp/
```

EDIT 2:
Everything can be moved to another temporary location except for the `systemd-private-72f0212651f2433dbce43b96e2dea612-cups.service-9OArRS`

It gives me this error: `mv: cannot move ‘systemd-private-72f0212651f2433dbce43b96e2dea612-cups.service-9OArRS/’ to ‘/home/chris/moveto/systemd-private-72f0212651f2433dbce43b96e2dea612-cups.service-9OArRS’: Operation not permitted`

However, it ^ can be moved with sudo.

Comment: Can you show us the output of mount, getenforce, and ls -ld /tmp?

Comment: Also, what happens if your try to move those files one by one to another temporary location outside of /tmp?

Comment: getenforce seems to have something to do with SELinux, which I'm pretty sure I'm not running...

Comment: That's a private `/tmp/` folder created for `cups` by systemd. You can remove it by stopping the cups service: `sudo systemctl stop cups`

Comment: Even after stopping `cups`, I'm still stuck at `rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/’: Device or resource busy`

Comment: Okay, so now the /tmp folder is empty correct?

Comment: One quick solution you can try is booting into single-user mode (which should prevent contention with other users and processes), removing the folder, and then rebooting.

Answer (score 1):

> "One quick solution you can try is booting into single-user mode
>   (which should prevent contention with other users and processes),
>   removing the folder, and then rebooting. – Paul Calabro"

Fixed! The boot process was so quick, I didn't even see the text screen!

I booted into recovery mode, entered the root password and did:

```
cd ..
rm -rf /tmp
mkdir /tmp
chmod 1777 /tmp
```

(The cd .. was to get to the root directory)

Thanks to user Paul Calabro and others!

Comment: Feel free to mark this answer as _Accepted_.  That will help other users identify this as a workable resolution.

Comment: Does not one have to remount tmp as rw ?