# List of Kill Signals

Tags: signals

I'm familiar with several process signals and what they do, but I would like to understand them all.

There are three things I would like to find out about each signal.

1. What the signal does
2. When a signal like this is typically sent
3. Any command line shortcuts or commands that are associated with them

Here is the list of signals and what I have so far.

```
0 - ? 
1 - SIGHUP - ?, controlling terminal closed, 
2 - SIGINT - interupt process stream, ctrl-C 
3 - SIGQUIT - like ctrl-C but with a core dump, interuption by error in code, ctl-/ 
4 - SIGILL 
5 - SIGTRAP 
6 - SIGABRT 
7 - SIGBUS 
8 - SIGFPE 
9 - SIGKILL - terminate immediately/hard kill, use when 15 doesn't work or when something disastrous might happen if the process is allowed to cont., kill -9 
10 - SIGUSR1 
11 - SIGSEGV 
12 - SIGUSR2
13 - SIGPIPE 
14 - SIGALRM
15 - SIGTERM - terminate whenever/soft kill, typically sends SIGHUP as well? 
16 - SIGSTKFLT 
17 - SIGCHLD 
18 - SIGCONT - Resume process, ctrl-Z (2nd)
19 - SIGSTOP - Pause the process / free command line, ctrl-Z (1st)
20 - SIGTSTP 
21 - SIGTTIN 
22 - SIGTTOU
23 - SIGURG
24 - SIGXCPU
25 - SIGXFSZ
26 - SIGVTALRM
27 - SIGPROF
28 - SIGWINCH
29 - SIGIO 
29 - SIGPOLL 
30 - SIGPWR - shutdown, typically from unusual hardware failure 
31 - SIGSYS
```

Comment: Read [`signal(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), it probably has all the info you're looking for...

Comment: Or `signal(3)` on *BSD, or there's also a chapter in APUE.

Comment: I think `SIGQUIT`'s keyboard shortcut is supposed to be `ctrl-\`

Comment: See also: [What causes various signals to be sent?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6332/114401)

Answer (score 98):

`man 7 signal` will show you a complete table with a brief summary of the meaning of each signal:

> ```
>    First the signals described in the original POSIX.1-1990 standard.
>
>    Signal     Value     Action   Comment
>    ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
>    SIGHUP        1       Term    Hangup detected on controlling terminal
>                                  or death of controlling process
>    SIGINT        2       Term    Interrupt from keyboard
>    SIGQUIT       3       Core    Quit from keyboard
>    SIGILL        4       Core    Illegal Instruction
>    SIGABRT       6       Core    Abort signal from abort(3)
>    SIGFPE        8       Core    Floating point exception
>    SIGKILL       9       Term    Kill signal
>    SIGSEGV      11       Core    Invalid memory reference
>    SIGPIPE      13       Term    Broken pipe: write to pipe with no
>                                  readers
>    SIGALRM      14       Term    Timer signal from alarm(2)
>    SIGTERM      15       Term    Termination signal
>    SIGUSR1   30,10,16    Term    User-defined signal 1
>    SIGUSR2   31,12,17    Term    User-defined signal 2
>    SIGCHLD   20,17,18    Ign     Child stopped or terminated
>    SIGCONT   19,18,25    Cont    Continue if stopped
>    SIGSTOP   17,19,23    Stop    Stop process
>    SIGTSTP   18,20,24    Stop    Stop typed at terminal
>    SIGTTIN   21,21,26    Stop    Terminal input for background process
>    SIGTTOU   22,22,27    Stop    Terminal output for background process
>
>    The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.
>
>    Next  the  signals  not  in  the POSIX.1-1990 standard but described in
>    SUSv2 and POSIX.1-2001.
>
>    Signal       Value     Action   Comment
>    ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
>    SIGBUS      10,7,10     Core    Bus error (bad memory access)
>    SIGPOLL                 Term    Pollable event (Sys V).
>                                    Synonym for SIGIO
>    SIGPROF     27,27,29    Term    Profiling timer expired
>    SIGSYS      12,31,12    Core    Bad argument to routine (SVr4)
>    SIGTRAP        5        Core    Trace/breakpoint trap
>    SIGURG      16,23,21    Ign     Urgent condition on socket (4.2BSD)
>    SIGVTALRM   26,26,28    Term    Virtual alarm clock (4.2BSD)
>    SIGXCPU     24,24,30    Core    CPU time limit exceeded (4.2BSD)
>    SIGXFSZ     25,25,31    Core    File size limit exceeded (4.2BSD)
>
>    Up to and including Linux 2.2, the default behavior for  SIGSYS,  SIGX‐
>    CPU,  SIGXFSZ,  and (on architectures other than SPARC and MIPS) SIGBUS
>    was to terminate the process (without a core  dump).   (On  some  other
>    UNIX systems the default action for SIGXCPU and SIGXFSZ is to terminate
>    the  process  without  a  core  dump.)   Linux  2.4  conforms  to   the
>    POSIX.1-2001  requirements  for  these signals, terminating the process
>    with a core dump.
>
>    Next various other signals.
>
>    Signal       Value     Action   Comment
>    ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
>    SIGIOT         6        Core    IOT trap. A synonym for SIGABRT
>    SIGEMT       7,-,7      Term
>    SIGSTKFLT    -,16,-     Term    Stack fault on coprocessor (unused)
>    SIGIO       23,29,22    Term    I/O now possible (4.2BSD)
>    SIGCLD       -,-,18     Ign     A synonym for SIGCHLD
>    SIGPWR      29,30,19    Term    Power failure (System V)
>    SIGINFO      29,-,-             A synonym for SIGPWR
>    SIGLOST      -,-,-      Term    File lock lost (unused)
>    SIGWINCH    28,28,20    Ign     Window resize signal (4.3BSD, Sun)
>    SIGUNUSED    -,31,-     Core    Synonymous with SIGSYS
>
>    (Signal 29 is SIGINFO / SIGPWR on an alpha but SIGLOST on a sparc.)
>
>    SIGEMT is not specified in POSIX.1-2001, but  nevertheless  appears  on
>    most  other UNIX systems, where its default action is typically to ter‐
>    minate the process with a core dump.
>
>    SIGPWR (which is not specified in POSIX.1-2001) is typically ignored by
>    default on those other UNIX systems where it appears.
>
>    SIGIO (which is not specified in POSIX.1-2001) is ignored by default on
>    several other UNIX systems.
>
>    Where defined, SIGUNUSED is synonymous with SIGSYS  on  most  architec‐
>    tures.
> ```

Comment: Ahh!  I think SIGKILL/9 - the premeditated savage *murder* of a process - is my personal favorite... so much more satisfying than SIGTERM/15 - to just telling the process to "shut-up and die!" (but clean up after yourself first).

Comment: Yeah, but too much savage murder can lead to a horde of zombies, which is never good.

Comment: Knew there was some man pages on this, didn't know where to look though.

Comment: @Dave, use `apropos` in Linux/Unix to search through man pages. e.g., `apropos signal`

Comment: For a quick number to signal name mapping `trap -l` (in bash) - that's lowercase L

Comment: DopeGhoti How does savage murder lead to a horde of zombies?  Well behaved parents will notice when their children are savagely murdered.  Well behaved parents that are savagely murdered will have their children adopted by pid 1.  pid 1 is immune to savage murder.  This is not how the zombie apocalypse will begin.

Comment: Zombie apocalypses are rarely caused by the well-behaved.

Comment: @BaardKopperud can't help myself saying that's my favorite too! : -D

Comment: *No manual entry for signal* – FreeBSD. Instead: `man 3 signal` – https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317492/list-of-kill-signals#comment558024_317492