# Why are the signal lists for kill, killall and pkill not the same?

Tags: linux, kill, signals, options, pkill

I researched the `kill`, `pkill` and `killall` commands, and I understood most of their differences. However, I am confused about their signals:

If I run `kill -l`, I see:

```
 1) SIGHUP       2) SIGINT       3) SIGQUIT      4) SIGILL       5) SIGTRAP
 6) SIGABRT      7) SIGBUS       8) SIGFPE       9) SIGKILL     10) SIGUSR1
11) SIGSEGV     12) SIGUSR2     13) SIGPIPE     14) SIGALRM     15) SIGTERM
16) SIGSTKFLT   17) SIGCHLD     18) SIGCONT     19) SIGSTOP     20) SIGTSTP
21) SIGTTIN     22) SIGTTOU     23) SIGURG      24) SIGXCPU     25) SIGXFSZ
26) SIGVTALRM   27) SIGPROF     28) SIGWINCH    29) SIGIO       30) SIGPWR
31) SIGSYS      34) SIGRTMIN    35) SIGRTMIN+1  36) SIGRTMIN+2  37) SIGRTMIN+3
38) SIGRTMIN+4  39) SIGRTMIN+5  40) SIGRTMIN+6  41) SIGRTMIN+7  42) SIGRTMIN+8
43) SIGRTMIN+9  44) SIGRTMIN+10 45) SIGRTMIN+11 46) SIGRTMIN+12 47) SIGRTMIN+13
48) SIGRTMIN+14 49) SIGRTMIN+15 50) SIGRTMAX-14 51) SIGRTMAX-13 52) SIGRTMAX-12
53) SIGRTMAX-11 54) SIGRTMAX-10 55) SIGRTMAX-9  56) SIGRTMAX-8  57) SIGRTMAX-7
58) SIGRTMAX-6  59) SIGRTMAX-5  60) SIGRTMAX-4  61) SIGRTMAX-3  62) SIGRTMAX-2
63) SIGRTMAX-1  64) SIGRTMAX
```

But `pkill -l` gives:

```
pkill: invalid option -- 'l'

Usage:
 pkill [options] <pattern>

Options:
 -<sig>, --signal <sig>    signal to send (either number or name)
 -e, --echo                display what is killed
 -c, --count               count of matching processes
 -f, --full                use full process name to match
 -g, --pgroup <PGID,...>   match listed process group IDs
 -G, --group <GID,...>     match real group IDs
 -i, --ignore-case         match case insensitively
 -n, --newest              select most recently started
 -o, --oldest              select least recently started
 -P, --parent <PPID,...>   match only child processes of the given parent
 -s, --session <SID,...>   match session IDs
 -t, --terminal <tty,...>  match by controlling terminal
 -u, --euid <ID,...>       match by effective IDs
 -U, --uid <ID,...>        match by real IDs
 -x, --exact               match exactly with the command name
 -F, --pidfile <file>      read PIDs from file
 -L, --logpidfile          fail if PID file is not locked
 --ns <PID>                match the processes that belong to the same
                           namespace as <pid>
 --nslist <ns,...>         list which namespaces will be considered for
                           the --ns option.
                           Available namespaces: ipc, mnt, net, pid, user, uts

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see pgrep(1).
```

Even when there is no list of signals, this command supports/uses signals, just see in the previous output that appears

```
-<sig>, --signal <sig>    signal to send (either number or name)
```

And finally, `killall -l` returns:

```
HUP INT QUIT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE KILL USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM STKFLT
CHLD CONT STOP TSTP TTIN TTOU URG XCPU XFSZ VTALRM PROF WINCH POLL PWR SYS
```

**Question**

- Why are the ***signal lists*** for `kill`, `killall` and `pkill` not the same?

I assumed `pkill` and `killall` should had shown the same output as `kill -l` - and at first glance, it seems like `pkill` does not support signals.

**Environment:**

I have this situation for Ubuntu Server 18:04, 20:04 and Fedora  Workstation 36

Comment: Do we talk about Linux? Or UNIX?

Comment: `pkill` has no `-l` option, so you're just looking at the standard help message.

Comment: @RomeoNinov added the `Environment` section

Comment: @terdon agree, IMHO is expected offer/show the list of signals through `pkill` too

Comment: On the contrary, it's common for a command when it is given an argument it does not know to either say "what?" or to act as though it was invoked with `--help` or its equivelant.  Giving possible options for one specific argument in response to an _unknown_ argument would be a very odd design decision in my opinion.

Comment: Well, `pkill -l` (at least on my Arch) does something completely different. You should always read the man page before trying random options.

Comment: Yes, I know that `pkill -l` does not exist, but I assumed at a first glance that should had the same behavior than the other two commands, I mean list the signals - even if other _option_ could be used

Comment: @ManuelJordan, from where you make this assumption?

Comment: just a thought - if the 3 commands are related to kill processes, and 2 of them uses the `l` option to show the list of signals - I assumed `pkill` should offer the same, with the same option name or not.

Comment: @ManuelJordan, as I said in my answer: if the authors are different you can expect different options.

Comment: Just to complicate things further: Bash has a built-in `kill` command, so it does not even run the command `/bin/kill` which the man page describes: it is instead described in the Bash Reference Manual, and judging by your output, you are running that. It also accepts signal names with or without the `SIG` prefix. Other shells may also have built-ins, or not (you don't tag which specific shell you are using).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Why are the signal lists for kill, killall and pkill not the same?

Most likely, because they were implemented differently, with different frames of mind, at different times, by different persons.

You should note that all of the commands have some form of a `--signal` argument that can specify any signal the kernel is capable of sending, regardless of which signals the inline help or manual pages may have written into them by hand.  As always, consult a command's documentation (generally available in the manual with `man command`) for details on its usage, invocation, and options.  You can also check §7 of the manual for details- see [List of Kill Signals](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317492/list-of-kill-signals/317496) for instance.

Comment: According with your latest paragraph so I must assume the `pkill` and `killall` commands handle or can use in peace the same set of signals shown by `kill` command - am I correct?

Comment: No, do not assume.  Never assume.  As the idiom goes, "assumption makes an 'ass' out of 'u' and 'mption'".  Or something like that.  If you ever have questions about how to properly invoke a command, consult its documentation in the manual with `man command` or by asking the command for help with `command --help` (which is standard but not universal).

Comment: About assumptions, it goes in hand with experimentation - I think that is good for any learning path,  of course in controlled environments - For example - Linux through VirtualBox.

Comment: @ManuelJordan Each signal has a name and a number. Under the hood, the system call that a kill command has to make only accepts numbers. All the kill commands have an option to specify the signal as a number, and this is almost certain to be passed through unaltered. They also all have the option to specify by name (and will translate names into numbers), and are likely to assign the same names to the same numbers (especially for the widely used ones defined by the POSIX specification), but it's plausible some commands will differ in their support for uncommon signals.

Comment: @James_pic thanks, but giving 2 more cents, and just in case to share experience - in macos if is executed `kill -l` the list is different than in Linux. Therefore, it avoid problems according the code numbers, is better use the signal name for scripts purposes between these 2 OS

Comment: @ManuelJordan yes, and indeed if you run `man 7 signal` in Linux, you'll see that the list of signals supported, and their numbers, can vary between versions of Linux, and between Linux architectures. Names should be the most portable, but only the POSIX ones are likely to be widely supported.

Comment: @ManuelJordan - this comment chain is getting rather long, but in short, MacOS is derived from BSD, so its signals (and indeed its manual pages, and implementations of standardized binaries) differ from Linux to varying degrees of significance.

Comment: Unless I’m mistaken, the `kill` command actually generates the signal list that the `-l` option outputs at compile time (it realistically _needs_ to do this to also list the numbers, which are _not_ consistent across platforms (and even CPU architectures on Linux), especially since in C the signal names are only present as macros), while `killall` just has a static list of the commonly supported signal names.

Answer (score 9):

The programs you mention (`kill`, `killall` and `pkill`) with high probability have different authors. And each author decide how to provide help to the user. You can't expect they will have same command line, same options.

You should get in mind some people (including me) read man pages on the OS they work now to avoid entering wrong command :). Read the man page for `killall` for Linux, Solaris and AIX and you will be surprised

Comment: I see - I thought exists an explicit nomenclature acceptation for the signals name - for example `killall` does not respect it about the signals name. The `SIG` term part is not included.

Comment: @ManuelJordan, no. Linux is not controlled corporative development environment and you can't expect same list of options in programs with different purpose

Comment: I see now, thanks for the quick and polite support

Answer (score 1):

The `kill` program and `killall` show the same set of signals:

```
$ /bin/kill -l
HUP INT QUIT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE KILL USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM STKFLT
CHLD CONT STOP TSTP TTIN TTOU URG XCPU XFSZ VTALRM PROF WINCH POLL PWR SYS
$ killall -l
HUP INT QUIT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE KILL USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM STKFLT
CHLD CONT STOP TSTP TTIN TTOU URG XCPU XFSZ VTALRM PROF WINCH POLL PWR SYS
```

`kill` by itself is the shell built-in. `pkill` just shows no signal listings.

The `kill` built-in shows the same signals up to signal 31, with the exception of 29 which shows either `SIGIO` or `SIGPOLL`, which are synonyms for each other.

Signals above 31 are real-time signals and then some of them are nicked for threads, but they're "different" and generally less used than the ones below 31.