# Can't overwrite a file by moving another over it

Tags: permissions, mv, move

I have file `/some/foo` which is a plain text file. I can edit it with `vim` and I can `cat` something else to it. But whenever I try to automate the editing process with `sed`, it says

```
sed: cannot move '/some/sedGl29Uj': Device or resource busy
```

I tried redirecting `sed`'s output to a temporary file and `cat`, it's OK. But if I try to move the temporary file onto it, it will say

```
root@localhost:/some # mv tmp foo
mv: Device or resource busy
```

I'm quite concerned why `vim` and `cat` can write the file but `mv` can't.
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. `/some` is a subfolder of `/` (root mount point, ext4).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get over "device or resource busy"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11238/how-to-get-over-device-or-resource-busy)

Comment: Try: `mv ./tmp foo`

Comment: What filesystem and OS is this?

Comment: The difference between `vim` and `cat` on the one hand, and `sed -i` and `mv` on the other hand, is that `cat >/some/foo` writes to the existing file, whereas `mv /some/foo /some/bar` renames the file. This file can be written to, but can't be renamed. To understand why the file can't be renamed, we'd need to know more about this file and the filesystem that it's on and what OS you're running.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer when managing drive mounts. A strange line showed up when I was checking mounted drives.

```
~ # mount | grep /etc/hosts
/tmp/hosts on /etc/hosts type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,bind)
```

That made me surprised. After digging all the scripts that I've used, I found this line in a hosts modifier script

```
sudo mount -o bind /tmp/hosts /etc/hosts
```

Then I tried something else:

```
/tmp # echo aaa > a
/tmp # mount -o bind a b; cat b
aaa
/tmp # echo bbb > b; cat a
bbb
/tmp # echo ccc > c
/tmp # mv c b
mv: Device or resource busy
```

The solution is, of course, cancel that mount point:

```
sudo umount /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score -3):

It is likely you don't have write access to the directory. The file operations: create, delete and rename all modify the directory.

`cat` and `vim` just modify the file contents and don't need to modify the file.  `sed -i` writes a temporary file and renames it.

Comment: If I didn't have write access to thw directory, it **would have said** `Permission denied` instead of `Device or resource busy`. Also, `sed` wouldn't have been able to create the temp file without write access to the directory.