# Why the following error appears when using rm -rf * in my current location?

Tags: linux, nfs, rm

I have tried to remove all folders from my current directory using Linux command `rm -rf *`. But the following error occurs and the respected folder is also not deleted.

```
rm: cannot remove ‘Xenon_R3_S/Datapath_r/ver/.nfs000000000409508f0003f7b0’: Device or resource busy
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11238/how-to-get-over-device-or-resource-busy

Comment: See http://nfs.sourceforge.net/#faq_d2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that the file you are trying to delete is in use by a process.

Try: `lsof ${FILENAME}` to determine what process is using it, then you can kill it with the `kill` command if you really want to.