# "Device or Resource Busy"

Tags: lsof, delete

I am trying to delete a directory using

```
rm -rf dirName
```

But I receive a bunch of errors like:

```
rm: cannot remove 'deleteMe/icarus/.nfs0000001bcf11514a0000cd45': Device or resource busy
```

When I try to find out the processes using this file with the command

```
lsof deleteMe/icarus/.nfs0000001bcf11514a0000cd45
```

There is no output. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not even on the NFS server, or other hosts mounting the same directory?

Comment: Sorry, what does the first part mean?

Comment: The directory that you are trying to delete is mounted from an NFS file server. If a program on another host that mounts the same directory from that server has a file open, you won't be able to delete the directory.

Comment: Ohh I see. How do I check if a program on another host is mounting the directory and kill it?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same experience and I solved it with the aid of another thread on this same issue.

Read [How to get over "device or resource busy"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11238/how-to-get-over-device-or-resource-busy)

The contribution that helped me was:

```
ps -ef | grep name-of-busy-dir
```

Showed me the process and the PID (column two).

```
sudo kill -15 pid
```

Thereafter, delete your folder without any qualms.

Answer (score 0):

Another pretty much simple answer is following:

**1. Close all your terminal windows (bash, shell, etc...)**

**2. Start a new terminal**

**3. Execute your command again** e.g.:

```
rm -rf dirName
```

**4. done**

Hopefully it helps others!

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however that this would only work if there is no other user logged in who could be using the file or directory, and that this would also not work if it is a system process that occupies the resource rather than one started explicitly by the OP's user.

Comment: yes right, but on a single machine with single user, it should do it. A drastic answer will be a system restart or killing all processes that are using that resource

Comment: it is not a suitable Answer