# can't write to /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/*/energy_performance_preference when ac-adapter is connected

Tags: gentoo, cpu-frequency, sysfs

AC-adapter unplugged:

```
$ echo power | sudo tee energy_performance_preference
power
$ echo $?
0
```

AC-adapter plugged-in:

```
$ echo power | sudo tee energy_performance_preference
power
tee: energy_performance_preference: Device or resource busy
```

Yes, I have *intel p-states HWP*-capable CPU, otherwise i [wouldn't](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/admin-guide/pm/intel_pstate.html) have that setting above.

My laptop is running Gentoo Linux hardened with `5.17.4-gentoo-x86_64` kernel.

Maybe it's somehow related, but */var/log/syslog* shows that after unplugging adapter:

```
May 27 17:19:27 mathroom laptop-mode: enabled, active
May 27 17:19:27 mathroom rfkill: block set for type bluetooth
May 27 17:19:27 mathroom laptop-mode: LCD Brightness Command succeeded.
May 27 17:19:27 mathroom kernel: EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Quota mode: disabled.
May 27 17:19:27 mathroom kernel: EXT4-fs (sda4): re-mounted. Quota mode: disabled.
May 27 17:19:27 mathroom kernel: r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Down
May 27 17:19:28 mathroom root: ACPI event unhandled: battery PNP0C0A:00 00000080 00000001
May 27 17:19:28 mathroom root: ACPI event unhandled: battery PNP0C0A:00 00000081 00000001
May 27 17:19:28 mathroom root: ACPI event unhandled: battery PNP0C0A:00 00000080 00000001
May 27 17:19:28 mathroom root: ACPI event unhandled: battery PNP0C0A:00 00000001 00000001
```

, and this after plugging it back in:

```
May 27 17:20:36 mathroom laptop-mode: enabled, active
May 27 17:20:36 mathroom rfkill: unblock set for type bluetooth
May 27 17:20:36 mathroom laptop-mode: LCD Brightness Command succeeded.
May 27 17:20:36 mathroom kernel: NMI watchdog: Enabled. Permanently consumes one hw-PMU counter.
May 27 17:20:36 mathroom kernel: EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Quota mode: disabled.
May 27 17:20:36 mathroom kernel: EXT4-fs (sda4): re-mounted. Quota mode: disabled.
May 27 17:20:36 mathroom kernel: r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Down
May 27 17:20:36 mathroom root: ACPI event unhandled: battery PNP0C0A:00 00000080 00000001
May 27 17:20:36 mathroom root: ACPI event unhandled: ac_adapter ACPI0003:00 00000080 00000001
May 27 17:20:37 mathroom root: ACPI event unhandled: battery PNP0C0A:00 00000081 00000001
May 27 17:20:37 mathroom root: ACPI event unhandled: battery PNP0C0A:00 00000080 00000001
May 27 17:20:37 mathroom root: ACPI event unhandled: battery PNP0C0A:00 00000001 00000001
```

Also, there's no `diff`-erence in */etc/mtab* before and after changing adapter state.

It's worth noting that at the time ac-adapter IS connected, i CAN write to `scaling_governor`, for example, but not to `energy_performance_preference`.

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11238/how-to-get-over-device-or-resource-busy) post didn't help me(`lsof +D /sys` output is unrelated).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?

Answer (score 2):

What is the output of the following commands (I know this question would better fit into to a comment but I don't have enough reputation yet):

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/*/energy_performance_available_preferences  
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/*/scaling_governor
```

On my Arch Linux with `amd_pstate_epp` when my `scaling_governor` is set to `performance` I can only select `performance` as EPP preference (`energy_performance_available_preferences` also only contains `performance` then). When I then try to select an unavailable EPP preference I get the `Device or resource busy` error. Maybe plugging in your AC-adapter changes your governor setting?

```
$ uname -a
Linux some-hostname 6.7.4-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon, 05 Feb 2024 22:07:49 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/
$ echo powersave | sudo tee scaling_governor
powersave
$ cat energy_performance_available_preferences
default performance balance_performance balance_power power
$ echo power | sudo tee energy_performance_preference 
power
$ echo performance | sudo tee scaling_governor
performance
$ cat energy_performance_available_preferences       
performance
$ echo power | sudo tee energy_performance_preference
power
tee: energy_performance_preference: Device or resource busy
```

The exact reason for this, however, is beyond my knowledge.